# Authenticating to Azure Devops Git repo

Tags: c#, asp.net, libgit2sharp

We are working on a system to automatically commit generated projects into Git repositories located in Azure Devops. We want to use libgit2sharp for this. We want the user to authenticate using their Microsoft account, grab the Access Token(jwt) from the authentication request and use that as means of authentication. But we cannot seem to get this working.

In another post I read 2 other authentication methods: 1. Alternative accounts. 2. Personal Access Tokens, PAT. Both made in the profile sections of your devops account.

I can get Alternative accounts to work perfectly but this is not our preferred route as it will require extra actions from the user. The PAT does not seem to work for me and throws me an error that there were "too many redirects or authentication replays". I figured this is because of the two factor authentication that is enabled on the Microsoft account.

Is it even supported to use an Access Token(jwt) in LibGit2Sharp with 2FA enabled?

```
using (var repo = new Repository({repo location}))
            {
                foreach (var file in file)
                {
                    repo.Index.Add(file.Path);
                    repo.Index.Write();
                }

                var author = new Signature("{name}", "{name}", DateTime.Now);
                var committer = author;

                repo.Commit("Here's a commit i made!", author, committer);

                var options = new PushOptions();
                options.CredentialsProvider = (url, user, cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials() { Username = "{username}", Password = "{password}" };

                repo.Network.Push(repo.Branches["master"], options);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Personal Access Tokens (PAT) **do bypass** MFA so that is probably not the error you're getting. A PAT is your best option, at the moment of the push you need the `remote-url` of your local Git repo to be as follows:

```
https://pat:{PAT_HERE}@dev.azure.com/...
```

**e.g.**

```
https://pat:gaakbfootuial7ksj4uv55o52335tyhhaasbqdvbg5xgyy33t754@dev.azure.com/auroraloop/devenv/_git/devenv
```

**Tips:**

- The PAT will take the permissions of the Azure DevOps user that generated it so the user must have contribute permissions to the repo.
- You **cannot automate PAT creation**, you must have it upfront stored somewhere, if you don't want to hardcode this (you shouldn't) consider using an Azure Key Vault to store and retrieve the value I'm sure they have c# libraries.

The `options.CredentialsProvider` part of your code is probably doing exactly what I mentioned about the `remote-url` try setting it as follows:

```
options.CredentialsProvider = (url, user, cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials() { Username = "pat", Password = "{PAT_HERE}" };
```

Hardcode the PAT for **testing** and if successful take a look at the Azure Key Vault approach.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use a jwt received from the Microsoft login provider? Because that is what we are looking for. The PAT just has the extra obstacle of making it, and then we need to explain that to people, they have to go to devops to create it and then it expires and they have to create it again.. That is why we just want to use the token we receive from logging in to the Microsoft login provider built into our app, so it is more user friendly. So is this possible too?

Comment: SDKs usually take care of that headache for **authentication** but since you're specifically interested in Git operations I don't think a jwt token will work. From my perspective these are two different things, a jwt token authenticates a user against Azure DevOps Services after completing the sign in form. I believe that Git operations happen on **authorization** grounds meaning the jwt token is no longer in the picture because the user is already authenticated and Git simply asks for appropriate permissions of the account it sees. I may be wrong though.

Comment: You can actually generate PATs now programmtatically. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#pattokenresult